Spring Boot Migration to 3.x Slows Down Tests: Impact of Scheduled Methods
Problem
I recently migrated a Spring Boot application from version 2.7.3 to 3.3.6. After the migration, I noticed that my test suite, which used to take about 2 minutes, now takes 15 minutes to execute.
Workaround
After investigating, I found that disabling scheduling (to turn off methods annotated with @Scheduled) brings the test execution time back to normal. However, I have some tests that depend on scheduled jobs, so I cannot disable them entirely.
Investigation
I compared debug logs from the old and new versions, no big difference. The only suspicious thing is that with the new version, gradle is trying to acquire and release a lock and it repeats every 10 seconds (same as the scheduled methods in the app)
2024-12-16T19:17:08.450+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:08.451+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:08.451+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:08.451+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:08.452+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:18.448+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:18.448+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:18.449+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:18.449+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:18.449+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:18.449+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:28.451+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:28.452+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:28.453+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:28.454+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:28.454+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-12-16T19:17:28.455+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.

Questions
What could cause scheduled methods to significantly slow down test execution after upgrading Spring Boot?
Are there any changes or configurations in Spring Boot 3.x related to scheduling that could affect this behaviour?
How can I ensure scheduled methods work in my tests without drastically increasing execution time?

It's going to be difficult to answer without any examples of your tests. Have you tried debugging?
